# Why does my node script stop running after a while?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, setinterval, pm2

I have a fairly simple script that I want to run on loop, the script should run 3 different fuctions every 2 minutes using a setInterval(). It looks something like this...

```
app.listen(port, () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
  }, 1000 * 120)
})
```

Each function makes a call to a different API, restructures the layout of the data that's returned and then sends all the data to a mongodb database. The success rate of each function is about 95-99% when I run it using "npm run server.js", and when one function fails, it has no effect on the next time the function is run so I don't mind one of the functions failing every now and then. My problem is, I've now hosted this node app on an ec2 server using pm2 so it constantly runs, but after 30 minutes or so one of the functions will stop adding results to the database, and then a bit later another function will stop and then finally they will all stop.

So am I doing something wrong? Should I be hosting the node app differently, or should I not be using this setInterval() setup?

Comment: Use pm2 to get more info about the failure  `pm2 list` `pm2 log`

Comment: I think it's because when I was using query and .then/.catch to remove the old data and then add the new data, but on occasions it was adding the new data first for some reason. So I changed it to async await and it seems to work now, although I thought they were the same?

Comment: You will have to show your promise impl and your async await impl